# while read nao funciona em script shell Unix

Tags: while, shell-script, ssh, unix

Estou programando um script e ao utilizar o `while read` duas vezes ele faz o 1 apenas uma vez:

```
un=$(echo $LOGNAME | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
grep -v '^#' nodeteste.txt > auxiliar.txt
while read line
do
  ssh "$un@$line" "cat arquivo" > arquivo.externo
  cut -d "," -f 1 arquivo.externo > arquivo.externo.cut
  uniq arquivo.externo.cut > arquivo.externo.cut.uniq
  while read line2
  do
   valor=$(grep -c "$line2 " arquivo.base)
   if [ $valor -eq 0 ]; then
     echo $line >> arquivo.base.diferente
     echo $line2 >> arquivo.base.diferente
     grep -i "$line2," arquivo.externo >> arquivo.base.diferente
     echo $line $line2 $valor "eh diferente"
   fi
  done < arquivo.externo.cut.uniq
done < auxiliar.txt
rm auxiliar.txt
```

ele executa o primeiro `while` apenas umas vez, estou desconfiado que ele perdei o stdin/out em algum momento!! Alguem poderia dar alguma dica!!

Answer (score 0):

Achei o problema, o ssh usa a stdin causando o problema de parar o 1 loop apos apenas 1 passada, quando uso a opcao -n ele redireciona o stdin parando o problema.

Problem source:

ssh "$un@$line" "cat arquivo" > arquivo.externo

Works source:

ssh -n "$un@$line" "cat arquivo" > arquivo.externo

SSH Manual: -n Redirects stdin from /dev/null (prevents reading stdin).